# Report code coverage from a deployment

Tags: apex, unit-test, deployment, code-coverage

Is there a way to get a report of the code coverage during or from a deployment?

Currently I have **85%** total coverage in my production (cleared all test and ran all test to be sure this is accurate), but when I'm deploying a very simple change right now (not even enough lines of code to offset my current coverage) I get 57/57 **100% successful test** but failed deployment because of *74% coverage*.

My guess is since the code I'm deploying is so minor (even if no lines were covered I'd still have enough total coverage), is that something is failing (silently) causing previous code in production to no longer be covered. Unfortunately I can't see what files are short based from this deployment because the only report I get back is 74% and no test failures :(

Appreciate the help

**UPDATE:**

I posted a ticket to SF support. Took a few days to get a response and initially they wouldn't even help because we apparently do not have developer support (typical SalesForce support to not even read your problem before quoting you your licensing limits).

Anyways, after a call to a sales rep they they finally looked into the issue and responded with the following:

> Connection User  04/01/2015 10:09:34 AM PDT
>
> Hi Nick,
>
> I further checked on this and found that **yes we are experiencing
>   issues with test class at our end**.
>
> The bad line coverage issues as you mentioned on stack trace has *not
>   been identified as bug though* but I checked that many customers are
>   complaining the same.
>
> Since this is been complained by plenty of customers our R & D team
>   will take notice on it and *might* create a public known issue link for
>   customers.
>
> **There are other issues too , related to test class only, for instance**
>   - https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T4oRAAS
>
> Bottom line is - as of now no known issue is *published* for your
>   concerned problem however I confirm that other users are also facing
>   the same **so we might see a bug link on it**.
>
> **Recompilation and clearing Test execution history might help but
>   sometimes it doesn't**.
>
> Kindly let me know if you have any other concern too regarding this.
>
> Thanks, Ashish Developer support salesforce.com

So that's that for now I take it. For now my best results have come from using the [HaoIDE](https://github.com/xjsender/haoide) add-on with Sublime and getting test result back from there. Also in the Developer Console I've found other perspectives that give more detailed information per each test I run. I'll post more follow up as I have it.

Comment: 85% in your dev org or your production ? A few things to check - that you are not using seeAllData=true on your test methods and that all validation rules, formulas & workflows that may be used or triggered in your tests match what you have dev'd against..

Comment: I do have a couple methods that use `seeAllData=true` at the time I found there is no other way for those test. I know we have validations, formulas, WF, etc, but they've not been an issue before not sure what would change especially if the deployment doesn't report that to me some how

Comment: Ok check that the data you require for the test method actually exists in the org, you can check the deployment log by going to setup -> deployment status -> view details although not sure that will be much help if its successful.

Comment: I think SF did change code coverage functionalty. Check my answer here: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F0000000B27eIAC

Comment: @SImon this matches my experience as well! I've had to move some of my static variables because they seem to be causing issues all a sudden even though they were fine before. Also last night I finally bumped CC to 86% thinking I would make 75% during deployment... turns out I was right BUT after successful deployment I cleared history and tested everything again and currently still have 86% CC. Basically the results are the most inconsistent thing right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To follow through with the solution for this post, I've since got more details and a **[solution posted here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/71099/10834)**. Essentially there are some glitches with testing between perceived coverage and actual coverage. This solution helps to clarify the two and provides steps to clear the aggregate table that stores results causing some of the inconsistencies.